# Is it idiomatic to use "as" in "He lives in the same building as you"?

Tags: conjunctions, idiomatic-language

> He lives in the same building **as** you.

Do native speakers use "as" in sentences like the above one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Completely idiomatic. A moment's googling finds many examples of this exact sentence:

> "I think you know my brother, Frank, he lives in the same building as you," he replied. So that's how he knows about me. Through Frank. So Frank talks about me to his brother? Interesting.